# django storing a multichoicefield from a form, it says the field can't be null

Tags: python, django

I have modelform_factory form embedded in my template which has a field with a foreignkey, It is a multichoicefield widget and when I click on it it shows me all the options available, but with same name' (like 'modelname_object',i guess that's because i haven't set their unicode name). after I post the form, the dict has a value in that field like [u'/1] or sometimes [u'/2] depending on what i choose. and then when I store error shows up

> (1048, "Column 'class_room_id' cannot be null")
>   Request Method:    POST

exception type: Integrity error

here's the code

```
def test(request):
    studentFormSet = modelform_factory(Student, fields=("class_room",))
    return render(request,'form.html',{'studentForm': studentFormSet})

if request.POST:
    name = request.POST['student name']
    standard = request.POST['class_room']
    roll_no = request.POST['roll no.']
    shatra = Student()
    shatra.name = name
    shatra.standard = Class_room.objects.all().filter(pk=standard)
    shatra.roll_no = roll_no
    shatra.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I would deduce that your Student model has a class_room ForeignKey. However when you create shatra you don't set the value of shatra.class_room, hence the error.

Anyway you should read the documentation about django forms and django modelforms. You are not using them in the proper way...

Comment: I got it dude, I am totally sorry, actually I have changed the field name from shatra.standard to shatra.class_room, was trying to reuse my old code